# How to list all resources belong to one user in flask-appbuilder, instead of all?

Tags: flask-appbuilder

I have briefly browsed the document for flask-appbuilder. In most examples, ModelView will list all resources. If there are related views, FAB allows admin(user) to check related items detail according to its relationship definitions.

However, I have no clue how to display resoruces belong to current users. In other frameworks, it is easy to implement that by custom SQL queries (where statement). But I didn't find demo project with sql queries from FAB examples, except some database testdate insertion code.

For example, let us image an IoT related project. Owners have many devices, and one device can be used by many users. Therefore,

- as admin, he/she should be able to see all devices.
- as owner, he/she should be able to see all devices belongs.
- as users, he/she should be able to see all devices he/she can use.

**models.py**

```
class Account(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = Column(String(128), unique = True)
    password = Column(String(128))
    email = Column(String(128))
    cellphone = Column(String(32))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.username

class Device(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    snr = Column(String(256), unique = True)
    name = Column(String(128))
    addr = Column(String(256))
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    status = Column(Enum('init','normal','transfer','suspend'), default = 'init')
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))    
    owner = relationship("Account")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Access(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(128))
    submit = Column(Date)
    approve = Column(Date)
    status = Column(Enum('init','approve','reject','expire'), default='init')
    dev_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('device.id'))
    device = relationship("Device")
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))    
    user = relationship("Account")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class AccessView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Access)

    label_columns = {}
    list_columns = ['device','owner','submit','approve']    

class DeviceView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    related_views = [ApplicationView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 
        'owner_id':'Owner'}
    list_columns = ['name','snr','addr','owner']
    edit_columns = ['name','snr','owner','addr','latitude','longitude','status']
    add_columns = edit_columns

    show_fieldsets = [
        ('Summary',
            {'fields':['name','snr','owner']}
        ),
        ('Device Info',
            {'fields':['addr','latitude','longitude','status'],'expanded':True}
        ),
    ]

@expose('/mine')
def mine(self):
    msg = "Mine Assets"
    return self.render_template('testpage.html', msg = msg)

@expose('/granted')
def granted(self):
    msg = "Granted Assets"
    return self.render_template('testpage.html', msg = msg)

db.create_all()

appbuilder.add_view(DeviceView,
    "My Devices",
    icon = "fa-heart",
    category = "Devices",
    category_icon = "fa-microchip")

appbuilder.add_view(AccountView,
    "Account",
    icon = "fa-group",
    category = "Devices")

appbuilder.add_view(AccessView,
    "Access",
    icon = "fa-handshake-o",
    category = "Devices")
```

If we defined following URLs for three views:

- admin, /deviceview/list
- owner, /deviceview/mine
- user, /deviceview/granted

However, I have no idea how to write methods of mine/granted. By using db.session.query() ?

**db.session.query(Device, owner=owner)** or **db.session.query(Access, user=user)**

Or any document I haven't read yet?

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution for that, at least partial of the answer. Besides DeviceView for admin, I defined another DeviceXView (as temp. name) as device list for current user, and using base_filter to narrow down the dataset from Model.

```
class DeviceXView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    base_filters = [['owner', FilterEqualFunction, get_user],]
    related_views = [ApplicationView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 
        'api_dev_id':'Device ID', 
        'api_dev_key':'Device Key',
        'api_id':'API ID',
        'api_key':'API Key',
        'owner_id':'Owner'}
    list_columns = ['name','snr','addr','owner']
    edit_columns = ['name','snr','owner','addr','latitude','longitude','status','api_id','api_key','api_dev_id','api_dev_key']
    add_columns = edit_columns

    show_fieldsets = [
        ('Summary',
            {'fields':['name','snr','owner']}
        ),
        ('Device Info',
            {'fields':['addr','latitude','longitude','status','api_id','api_key','api_dev_id','api_dev_key'],'expanded':True}
        ),
    ]
```

That is for all devcies owned by current user. In order to display all devices which the user can access, We can define AccessView and DeviceView as related View.